# Create common function or include js file in postman?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, postman

I have a common block of code to do some parsing that I use in many postman test scripts verbatim.

Is there any way I can place this function in a central location and reference it from my tests, instead of copy + pasting over and over?

This is using the postman for windows desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your external js contents in an environment variable and then load it with:

```
eval(postman.getGlobalVariable("environment variable key"));
```

[github issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180)